# Method undefined in child class

Tags: php, object

```
<?php

abstract class file
{
    private $pid;
    private $uid;
    public function  __construct($pid,$uid)
    {
        $this->pid = $pid;
        $this->uid = $uid;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        if($_SESSION['level']<$this->pid)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    public function allow()
    { 
        return "This is all right!";
    }

}
?>



    <?php
    // put your code here
    include("../file.php");
    session_start();
    class android extends file
    {
        public function __construct($pid,$uid)
        {
            parent::__construct($pid, $uid);

        }
    }

    $uid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $pa = new android(1,$uid);
    if($pa->valid())
            echo $pa->allow();
    else
            echo "<h1>No permission<h1>"

    ?>
```

The above class is android class and the one above that is file.. Now when the android extends(inherits) the file class, it means it has all the methods. But when I try to run the program, it says undefined variable android::allow()
I dont understand because I have defined the allow() function in the file class and so the android class should inherit the method as well.
please help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?  Also, do you perhaps have two files named file.php and the wrong one is being loaded or something?  At first glace, this looks ok.

Comment: Have to agree, there must be something you're omitting. This code runs fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php ,

> Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated

If your file class doesn't have any abstract method, don't bother declaring it as abstract, otherwise avoid calling the constructor ;)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method android::allow() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dakshh12\android.php on line 29

This is the  error I got..
Moreover the valid() function runs just fine even though it is defined in the parent class!

Comment: Indeed I missed that valid() is called without causing trouble... @bkconrad seems to have tested the code ("runs fine"), so yes, there must be something you're omitting. Probably nothing but the error you give happens on line 29, but - assuming "<?php" is on line 1 of android.php - the call to $pa->allow() is on line 17. Plus, the android class is not fully declared here, as there is no ending '}' (what's below the code you posted?).